# how to disable the data of many to many field in admin site

Tags: python, django

## model.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    employeeid=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=True)
    fullname=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    location=models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone=models.IntegerField('phone number')
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fullname

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname
```

## admin.py

```
class holidayAdmin(FilterUserAdmin):
    form = select2_modelform(holiday,attrs={'width': '250px'})
    fields= ('type','start_date','end_date','employees','image_ref','note',)
    list_display = ('type','created_by','last_modified_by','start_date',
    'end_date','note','employees')
```

error 
ERRORS:
: (admin.E109) The value of 'list_display[6]' must not be a ManyToManyField.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ManyToMany fields in list_display in the admin.
Simply change `list_display` to

```
list_display = ('type','created_by','last_modified_by','start_date',
                'end_date','note')
```

Comment: so, what will be the best solutions 

thank you for your answer